# How to Convert enum field to a String in a spring boot application saving to a mysql varchar columnm

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an enum class with user types admin, client and supplier. I have annotated my userType attribute in the User Model class with @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) . However, i have an error of type mismatch when i run my code.

I'm using spring boot and mysql database with varchar for the Enum usertype field. my below code has more in details.

**My enum class**

**UserType.java**

```
   public enum UserType {

     CLIENT ("Client"),
     SUPPLIER ("Supplier"),
     ADMIN ("Admin");

     private final String type;

     UserType (String userType){

       this.type = userType;

     }

     public String getType() {

       return this.type;
     }
   }
```

**User.java**

**code snippet for the UserType utype.**

```
@Entity
public class User{

 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Column (name = "user_type", nullable = false)
 private UserType utype;

 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 public UserType getUtype() {

   return utype;
 }

 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 public void setUtype(UserType utype) {
   this.utype = utype;
 }
}
```

**Controller**

```
   @GetMapping(value="/newUser")
   public String registrationForm(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("user", new User());
     model.addAttribute("UserTypes", UserType.values());

     return "register";
   }

  @PostMapping(value="/registerUser")
  public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user){

        userService.save(user);
        return "pages/login";
   }
```

**ThymeLeaf View File**

**register.html**

```
     <select th:field="*{utype}" >
      <option th:each="usertype : ${UserTypes}"
             th:text="${usertype.type}"
     th:value="utype">
    </option>
    </select>
```

**I expected the input for the utype to be converted to string but i'm having the following error.**

Field error in object 'user' on field 'utype': rejected value [utype]; codes [typeMismatch.user.utype,typeMismatch.utype,typeMismatch.com.grocery.demo.Model.UserType,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.utype,utype]; arguments []; default message [utype]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.grocery.demo.Model.UserType' for property 'utype'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Enumerated @javax.persistence.Column com.grocery.demo.Model.UserType] for value 'utype'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.grocery.demo.Model.UserType.utype]]

**mysql is configured using application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FredSystems
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=fred@2017
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.messages.basename=validation


 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: can you share the database entry for which you are fetching the data

Comment: did you check what is returning in utype ? most probably an object

Comment: i have posted the error log, Field error in object 'user' on field 'utype': rejected value [utype]; i don't understand what is going wrong

Comment: i have posted my database connection @AmitD

Comment: try having Enumerated and Column annotation on only get method for utype. if you are still getting the error can you provide a row of your database entry.

Comment: | user_type | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |

Comment: "try having Enumerated and Column annotation on only get method for utype."

this one is changing the database from varchar to integer

Comment: I think you only need the Enumated annotation on the field, you don't have to put it on the getter/setter. could you remove it and post what happens?

Comment: @gybandi the error is still the same as the one that i posted

Comment: I have the user object in my thymeleaf .

<form action="#" th:action="@{/registerUser}"   th:object="${user}"  method="post" >

th:object should represent everything fine

Comment: ah I see. From the exception I see that there is a message resolver defined somewhere in the app. Perhaps the problem comes from the internationalization of the app. could you provide the relevant rows from your messages.properties, if any?

Comment: disregard my previous comment, could you post a more complete stack trace?

Comment: i don't have messages.properties

the error i posted is all that my console is throwing

Comment: @FredKibuchi I tried your code snippets in a stand alone application and it works for me. the only difference is that i used H2 db instead of MySQL. It seems to me that something is passing the 'utype' as a possible value for the UserType enum, which is wrong. Is there any other logic around the register.html thymeleaf template worth mentioning? or perhaps you list the users somewhere else, and the db contains a row that has 'utype' in the user_type column?

Comment: @gybandi Thank you for this feedback, atleast it's encouraging that my code is working on your end. However, i have given out all my code here. So i don't understand where the UserType enum is getting passed.

Comment: I will push that up to github when I get home, so you could have a look, maybe you will find the solution in the differences.

Comment: @gybandi i will appreciate to look into it. Kingly vote for my question.

Comment: @FredKibuchi I've uploaded a demo project [here](https://github.com/gybandi/spring-ui-demo). I've generated a few records in the db, to check if the presentation layer is working as intended

Comment: @gybandi , i have seen your code, which database are you using, i see you have hard coded your users. @GetMapping(value = "/newUser"), GetMapping has no issue with me, my issue is while posting

Comment: @FredKibuchi I'm confused. I thought you only had this GetMapping endpoint. If there is anything else, please update your question or better yet, upload your project (if it's public) to github.

Comment: @gybandi see i have updated my question by adding my PostMapping in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as simple as below :

## Controller

```
 @GetMapping(value="/newUser")
   public String registrationForm(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("user", new User());
     model.addAttribute("UserTypes",Arrays.asList(UserType.values()));
     return "register";
   }
```

In your thymeleaf:

```
<select th:field="*{utype}" >
      <option th:each="usertype : ${UserTypes}"
             th:text="${usertype}"
     th:value="${usertype}">
    </option>
    </select>
```

If JSP:

```
<select id="editState"class="form-control">
                        <c:forEach items="${UserTypes}" var="ut" varStatus="loop">
                            <option value="${ut}">${ut}</option>
                        </c:forEach>                        
                    </select>
```

Comment: can you clean the project and build again ??

Comment: kindly see my updated code above including the PostMapping of the controller

Answer (score 0):

in your enum add this method

```
public static UserType getByName(String name) {
        for (UserType type : UserType.values()) {
            if (type.getName().equals(name)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

in your thymeleaf

```
<select th:field="*{utype}" >
      <option th:each="usertype : ${UserTypes}"
             th:text="${usertype.type}"
     th:value="${utype.type}">
    </option>
    </select>
```

and then from backend try to use getByName method to parse your HTML input.

Comment: hey buddy, check that i have added my PostMapping that i'm using to submit data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to have a field in enum which exactly matches your ENUM value. This will ease in fetching any enum

e.g.

```
public enum UserType {

 CLIENT ("CLIENT","Client"),
 SUPPLIER ("SUPPLIER","Supplier"),
 ADMIN ("ADMIN","Admin");

 private final String type;
 private final String name;

 UserType (String name, String userType){
   this.name=name;
   this.type = userType;

 }

 public String getType() {

   return this.type;
 }
```

}

For your purpose you can try overriding toString() method according to your values.

Comment: So do you approve my PostMapping controller?? is it okay according to your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your register.html:

```
   <select th:field="*{utype}" >
      <option th:each="usertype : ${UserTypes}"
             th:text="${usertype.type}"
     th:value="utype">
    </option>
    </select>
```

In the th:value tag you use an incorrect reference to the *utype* field. You should use a variable expression, where you declare what **value** you want to bind to your User object's utype **field**. So it should be something like this:

```
   <select th:field="*{utype}" >
      <option th:each="usertype : ${UserTypes}"
             th:text="${usertype.type}"
     th:value="${usertype}">
    </option>
    </select>
```

If it's still not working, please see my updated example project:
https://github.com/gybandi/spring-ui-demo